Eigen C++ divide operation on columns
I have a matrix df, and I am trying to fill my last columns by the ratio of 2 other columns like this:
df.col(0) = df.col(1).rowwise() / (df.col(1) + df.col(2));

Bu I get an error:
 error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct Eigen::internal::promote_scalar_arg<double, Eigen::Replicate<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true> >, -1, 1>, false>’

I do not understand what's wrong here. Anyone knows please?

Eigen makes a distinction between matrix types (which includes vectors) and array types. Arithmetic operations on matrices have matrix semantics. So a division of a matrix by a vector would be the inverse operation of a matrix multiplication by a vector. I assume that's not what you want.
What you want is a division of individual coefficients, which means you need array semantics. Do this:
df.col(0) = df.col(1).array().rowwise() / (
    df.col(1) + df.col(2)).array().transpose();

However, I don't really get the point of doing a rowwise() on a single column vector. Seems to me like you can just write
df.col(0) = df.col(1).array() / (df.col(1) + df.col(2)).array();

